# Viewing cells of a grid in sliding windows with periodic boundaries

Tags: python, numpy

Consider a 2D array

```
>>> A = np.array(range(16)).reshape(4, 4)
>>> A
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

I  would like to construct a function f(i,j) which pulls a 3x3 block from elements surrounding A[i,j] with periodic boundary conditions.

For example a non-boundary element would be

```
>>> f(1,1)
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 8,  9, 10]])
```

and a boundary element would be

```
>>> f(0,0)
array([[15, 12, 13],
       [ 3,  0,  1],
       [ 7,  4,  5]])
```

view_as_windows comes close but does not wrap around periodic boundaries.

```
>>> from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows
>>> view_as_windows(A,(3,3))
array([[[[ 0,  1,  2],
     [ 4,  5,  6],
     [ 8,  9, 10]],

    [[ 1,  2,  3],
     [ 5,  6,  7],
     [ 9, 10, 11]]],


   [[[ 4,  5,  6],
     [ 8,  9, 10],
     [12, 13, 14]],

    [[ 5,  6,  7],
     [ 9, 10, 11],
     [13, 14, 15]]]])
```

In this case view_as_windows(A)[0,0] == f(1,1) but f(0,0) is not in view_as_windows(A). I need a view_as_windows(A) type array which has the same number of elements as A, where each element has shape (3,3)

Comment: did u look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148292/how-do-i-select-a-window-from-a-numpy-array-with-periodic-boundary-conditions?

Comment: Thank you that's very helpful !

Comment: For efficient one use views - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831022

Comment: @Divakar this is not a solution because view_as_windows does not account for periodic boundary conditions

Comment: So, you are saying func `sub_A` would produce lesser elements for boundary elements from `A`?

Comment: I edited for more explanation-- I need to create a larger array as necessary containing A as blocks in order to draw 3x3 arrays which wrap around the boundaries of A. The boundary elements should be the same shape as all other elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pad with `wrapping` functionality using [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) and then use [Scikit's `view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

Apad = np.pad(A,1,'wrap')
out = view_as_windows(Apad,(3,3))
```

Sample run -

```
In [65]: A
Out[65]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [66]: Apad = np.pad(A,1,'wrap')

In [67]: out = view_as_windows(Apad,(3,3))

In [68]: out[0,0]
Out[68]: 
array([[15, 12, 13],
       [ 3,  0,  1],
       [ 7,  4,  5]])

In [69]: out[1,1]
Out[69]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 8,  9, 10]])
```

Comment: Thank you! That's excellent. If I wanted to generalize to 3D could I just use 

out = view_as_blocks(Apad,(3,3,3))?

Comment: @kevinkayaks Haven't tested, but I would think something like that.