# Vectorized extraction of submatrices in numpy-array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision, vectorization

My goal is to implement a median-filter, which is a function, that replaces each pixel in a (mostly) 2d-array with the median of its surrounding pixels. It can be used to denoise images.

My implementation extracts submatrices from the original matrix, that contain the pixel itself and its neighbors. This extraction is currently done with a for-loop and as you can imagine that for-loop takes away approximately 95% of execution-time.

Here is my current implementation:

```py
def median_blur(img, fsize=3):
    img_intermediate = np.zeros((img.shape[0] + 2, img.shape[1] + 2), np.uint8)  # First intermediate img, used for padding original image
    img_intermediate[1:img.shape[0]+1, 1:img.shape[1]+1] = img
    img_result = np.empty((*img.shape, fsize, fsize), np.uint8)  # Will contain result, first receives kernel-submatrices

    # Extract submatrices from image
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            img_result[i, j] = img_intermediate[i:i+fsize, j:j+fsize]

    img_result = img_result.reshape(*img.shape, fsize**2)  # Reshape Result-Matrix
    img_result = np.median(img_result, axis=2)  # Calculate median in one go
    return img_result.astype('uint8')
```

**How can i extract these submatrices using a vectorized operation?**

As a bonus, if someone with experience in computer-vision is reading this: Is there an better approach of implementing a median-filter other than applying it to an intermediate zero-padded matrix?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your use case is covered by the [median filter in scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.median_filter.html).

Comment: @edoput it is covered by several libraries (scipy, scikit-image, opencv...), but my goal is to implement it myself in the most performant way.

Comment: Use `view-as_windows` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831022/ and then use `np.median`?

Comment: @Divakar thanks for mentioning, i didn't know that function! It wouldn't be an only-numpy-solution but certainly would do what i want.

Comment: `view_as_windows` is a standalone function codebase. So, you can just pick it up from source.

Comment: Great, i will look into it. Can you formulate an answer out of what you told me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a vectorized solution. However, you can come up with a faster solution by paying attention to memory order of the image array:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

img_padded = np.pad(img, 1, mode='constant')
sub_shape = (fsize, fsize)
view_shape = tuple(np.subtract(img_padded.shape, sub_shape) + 1) + sub_shape
sub_img = as_strided(img_padded, view_shape, img_padded.strides * 2)
sub_img = sub_img.reshape(img.shape + (fsize**2,))
result = np.median(sub_img, axis=2).astype(int)
```

Use `pad` function to pad first and then `as_strided` to get the sub_matrices and finally apply `median` to your strides.

**UPDATE**: using `view_as_windows` suggested by @Divakar in comments:

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

img_padded = np.pad(img, 1, mode='constant')
sub_shape = (fsize, fsize)
view_shape = view_as_windows(img_padded, sub_shape, 1)
sub_img = view_shape.reshape(img.shape + (fsize**2,))
result = np.median(sub_img, axis=2).astype(int)
```

`view_as_windows` also provides sub-matrices similar to strides.

sample image and output:

```
img: 
[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9 10 11 12]
 [13 14 15 16 17 18]
 [19 20 21 22 23 24]]

median_filtered: 
[[ 0  2  3  4  5  0]
 [ 2  8  9 10 11  6]
 [ 8 14 15 16 17 12]
 [ 0 14 15 16 17  0]]
```

Comment: Beautiful! This made my existing solution approx. 7x faster! Can you elaborate on the possible memory-order gains?

Comment: Glad it helped. There might be a faster way of implementing this using numba or strided loops if you know your datatype. You would probably benefit from it if your array is saved in a `C-contiguous` manner (meaning rows first). `view_as_windows` will create a new array if your array is not `C-contiguous`. I would expect `as_strides` to do the same, but I am not sure. Generally speaking anything faster than this probably needs to get into `C-contiguous/F-contiguous` memory allocation and knowing your datatypes.