# python extract every possible nxn grid from large mxm grid

Tags: python, numpy, grid, extract

I have a grid of size (827,914) that I would like to extract every possible (5,5) grid from. The following code works as intented:

```
import numpy as np
N = 827
M = 914
gsize = 5
tmp = np.random.normal(0,1,(N,M))
alldata = np.zeros([(tmp.shape[0] - gsize + 1) * (tmp.shape[1] - gsize + 1),gsize, gsize])
county = 0

for i in range(0,tmp.shape[0] - gsize + 1):
    for j in range(0,tmp.shape[1] - gsize + 1):
        for k in range(i,i+gsize):
            for l in range(j,j+gsize):
                alldata[county,k-i,l-j] = tmp[k,l]
        county += 1
```

Which will return the correct data and array of size (748930,5,5). The problem is this code takes ~ 20-30 seconds to complete, and was hoping for something a bit more savvy / quicker. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can use [How to split a numpy array in fixed size chunks with and without overlap?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42831049) : `view_as_windows(tmp,(5,5))` to get a view as 3D array, which would be virtually free. You can then reshape to desired shape, but that forces a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be an application of `as_strided`:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

a = as_strided(tmp, ((N-gsize+1),(M-gsize+1),gsize,gsize), 
               (strides[1], strides[1]) + tmp.strides 
              ).reshape(-1, gsize, gsize)

print(a.shape)
# (748930, 5, 5)
```

Comment: shouldn't 'strides[1]' be 'tmp.strides[1]' ?

Comment: @M.Simpson Yes, I forgot to add `strides = tmp.strides` :-)

Comment: This works perfectly for the example. However, if I have a np.ndarray that also has a dtype=float32, for some reason it no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

I think Quang's answer is very cool.

Here's mine with some simple numpy indexing:

```
import numpy as np
N = 827
M = 914
gsize = 5
tmp = np.random.normal(0,1,(N,M))
alldata = np.zeros([(N - gsize + 1) * (M - gsize + 1),gsize, gsize])

ind = 0
for i in range(N - gsize + 1):
    for j in range(M - gsize + 1):
        alldata[ind] = tmp[i:i+gsize, j:j+gsize]
        ind += 1
print(alldata)
```